# Pass Value from .jsp to new page .jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to ask you , how to pass variable, there's the example:

I have variable String X in pageone.jsp then i open a new tab page to pagetwo.jsp (using JavaScript window.open) , Is it possible to use the variable X (from pageone.jsp) in pagetwo.jsp ? Please Explain, thank you verymuch!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

use `request.setAttribute("attribute_x", x);` to store the value of x in request in `page1.jsp` and then use `request.getAttribute("attribute_x").toString();` in the `page2.jsp` to retrieve the value.

You can also use `session` for this purpose (`session.setAttribute()` and `session.getAttribute()`)

Comment: would you (whoever voted down) mind posting a comment on why you voted this post down?? What is wrong with this??

Comment: what is the position of request.getAttribute("attribute_x").toString(); is it return String, or just setting new variable x?

Comment: request.getAtribute() returns an instance of Object which contains a String instance. You can also use (String)request.getAttribute()

Comment: the answer has been accepted. then why all are voting this down??

Comment: those who voted negative for this answer, take it back.. the answer has been accepted by the question owner

Answer (score 0):

You should store the variable name and value in a cookie.
And fetch the cookie value in the pagetwo.jsp.

OR

You can store the variable value in session.

Comment: No, don't. Cookies and sessions are for *persistent* data, not data that is just passed from one page to the next.

Comment: i'm prefer not using cookies :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the data in the URI, probably as a query string. Make sure you [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) it to make the data safe for URIs.

It sounds like the data starts out life in Java, so you'll need to include it in the page you send to the client for pageone. This is probably done most simply by setting up a data structure, encoding it using [JSON](http://json.org), and then assigning it to a variable in a `<script>` element.

Comment: What if the data he want to pass is some secret or a password ? It will be all shown in the URL.

Comment: There there should be some fiddling with making a POST request instead (just to keep it out of logs and the like).

Comment: @Nore — The same as you normally read query strings in JSP. I don't use JSP so I couldn't tell you the syntax, but it should be one of the first things you learn with any server side web language.

Answer (score 0):

Set the varaible into the session in **Page1.jsp** and access the same in **Page2.jsp.**

**In Page1.jsp**

```
session.setAttribute("X", "value");
```

**In Page2.jsp**

```
String x = session.getAttribute("X");
```